# Access LAN on Android without wifi

Tags: android, development-environment

I'm working on a web-app at work, and would like to access my development computer from my HTC Hero device. Preferably linux, but I have access to windows and mac computers. The emulator can debug locally, and helps a lot, but it's not good enough to debug real touch-events.

Ad-hoc wifi will breach our strict network policy. No matter how strict key or MAC-address restrictions it has.

Have anyone found a way to access the LAN through USB or Bluetooth? Bluetooth might be on the edge of our rules, but I will accept it as a solution if it's possible.

I'm not looking for Tethering, but rather the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use `adb ppp` in combination with `nc` to set up what you need. [This guy](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=522498) uses his laptop's internet connection over usb on his phone.

Comment: This looks promising :) But the scandinavian HTC Hero devices come without iptables :-/ Have heard some rumors of a patched ROM. Sounds scary, but guess I have to try it...

Comment: Found the ROM, but think I'll wait for the official update, and hope iptables is included.
http://android.modaco.com/content/htc-hero-hero-modaco-com/292018/01-09-1-4-modaco-custom-hero-rom-is-here/